# C - How to convert time_t to tm?

Tags: mysql, tm, time.h, time-t

I have a variable which using `time_t` data type. I want to convert this type into "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS". I just know if it's only works in `localtime()` example:

```
char buff[20];
time_t now = time(NULL);
strftime(buff, 20, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime(&now));
```

any suggestion how to convert it? because I have the time which always increased every minute, not the fixed one like the `localtime()`. I need this conversion for matching with `datetime` type in MySQL database.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The functions `gmtime` and `localtime` (for UTC and local time respectively) will turn an *arbitrary* `time_t` into a `struct tm` with individual fields for year, month and so on.

You can then just use `strftime` as you have, or `sprintf` to create strings from them, such as with:

```
char buff[11];
sprintf (buff, "%04d-%02d-%02d",
    mytm.tm_year + 1900,
    mytm.tm_mon + 1,
    mytm.tm_mday);
```

Comment: that two functions return the current time in a `tm` format. In this case, I had defined my own `time_t` to be converted into `tm`.

Comment: @Angga, those two functions have nothing to do with the current time. They will work on an arbitrary `time_t` value, either current time from `time(0)` or any other point in time like `(time_t)42`.

Comment: I've tried it but localtime() need const time_t *, while my variable is using time_t data type. I tried to cast it, or using localtime(&myvar) it made my program error. any solution?

Comment: Yes, post your error and let us have look, preferably in a new question since 1/ it's only tangentially related to this one and 2/ you'll get a broader respone than if you simply ask in a comment.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. after some editing, it's working now.

Comment: @nguyenmanh02123221, your comment seems to lack context. What is the actual question you're asking?

Comment: hi @paxdiablo, the title of this question seems inappropriate!
I was thinking of an answer such as: `localtime_s`

Comment: @nguyenmanh02123221, ah, that makes sense. However, the comment would probably  be better on the question in that case.